# Problem with placing a LinearLayout inside a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to place an image and some text in my view, with the image being twice the height of the text so that the two rows of text can be placed next to the image, like so:

```
 _____
|     |text here
|_____|text here
```

The way i try to do this is to put the two TextViews in a LinearLayout, then place the ImageView and the LinearLayout, containing the text, in a TableLayout with one row and two columns.

When i do this i only se the ImageView. In fact, even when i comment out the adding of the ImageView to the table the text inside the LinearLayout wont show up at all.

Any help with the code or different approaches to the layout is greatly appreciated.

```
LinearLayout tempVindLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    tempVindLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    tempVindLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TableLayout tabellLayout = new TableLayout(this);
    tabellLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    tabellLayout.setPadding(0, 60, 0, 0);

    TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
    row1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Textview saturday
    TextView tempSat = new TextView(this);
    tempSat.setText("+13");
    tempSat.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.RegularSmall);
    tempSat.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    // Wind saturday
    TextView vindSat = new TextView(this);
    vindSat.setText("5 m/s");
    vindSat.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.RegularSmall);
    vindSat.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    //Image for weather icons
    ImageView imgSat = new ImageView(this);
    imgSat.setImageResource(R.drawable.solmoln);
    imgSat.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    // Add to table
    tempVindLayout.addView(tempSat);
    tempVindLayout.addView(vindSat);

    row1.addView(tempVindLayout);
    row1.addView(imgSat);

    tabellLayout.addView(row1);

    setContentView(tabellLayout);
```

Comment: It is much easier to see what is going on if you use an xml file to create the layout, instead of doing it in code.

Answer (score 0):

The similar thing can be achieved using following layout...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/ImageView_01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ImageView_01">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView_01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header Text"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TextView_01"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this would be useful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```